# Change color add to cart button (flexgrid)

Tags: magento-1.9, css, custom, addtocart

I've been looking everywhere to change the css of this 'add to cart' button. The selector is .addtocart but when i change the css nothing changes...

```
.addtocart{
background-color: green;
}
```

I also cant find it anywhere in the css files.

[image]

Comment: use !important or Share your url...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `!imporatnt` in `css`

```
   .addtocart{
          background-color: green !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit code in below mentioned files

> magento/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/style.css

```
button,
.cart-table .product-cart-actions .button,
#co-shipping-method-form .buttons-set .button,
.footer .button {
     background: #000;
 }
```

I edited these background color and it worked for me on category page & product.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change code like below to implement

`.addtocart span span{
       background-color: green; 
}`